# Microsoft GraphAPI users delta doesn't return "assignedPlans" property on subsequent calls

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

When using the GraphAPI's Delta Query for `/users`, we have noticed that the `assignedPlans` property is only returned on the first call to `/delta`, but on all subsequent calls that use the `deltaLink` returned on the previous call, the property is consistently missing.

**The API call we make on the first call:**

```
GET https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/delta?$select=id,mail,givenName,surname,userType,displayName,givenName,userPrincipalName,businessPhones,jobTitle,mobilePhone,officeLocation,department,companyName,assignedPlans
```

This call's response does include the `assignedPlans` property for users, but on subsequent calls (using the `deltaLink`) - this property is missing.

Is this a known issue with the Delta Query?

Thank you!

Comment: Did you change the assigned plans for the specific users between subsequent queries? The delta queries only return what has changed.